# No Login for SQL Server but I am Local Admin

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssms, sqlcmd, sql-server-2012-express

I am a local Admin on my machine. Same old thing, my account wasnt added when SQL Server was installed, and I don't want to have to reinstall SQL Server. I went through this blog and it worked until I tried to log and run the commands via SQLCMD or SSMS. I got the error message

"Login failed for user '/'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.."

I found this blog and added the application name after the m switch http://sqlserver-help.com/2013/12/06/help-how-to-fix-error-reason-server-is-in-single-user-mode-only-one-administrator-can-connect-at-this-time/. But no dice, I still get the above error. The User Account looks fine I guess, I am an Administrator.

Also, I had to start the cmd prompt as an Admin to start sqlserver in single user mode. OR else I couldnt have access to the log files that the instance was using and it was giving me an error to that. So I ran the cmd prompt as admin. But still, I am the same admin trying to run SQLCMD or SSMS. It shoudlnt be telling me there is already an admin logged in, because I am that admin. What am I missing?

This is on SQLExpress, I dunno if that matters

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not just give me links to similar articles that I have already tried.  I only posted here after I ran into trouble after I tried those types of blogs

Comment: That single user mode is really killing you. Have you tried reinstalling it, with your account added as admin?

Comment: Reinstalling sql server?  I'm trying not to do that.  I could just reinstall I guess.  I would like to just add myself as a sql admin though.  I am pretty sure it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First login to the server:  `"sqlcmd –A –d master"`
.
connect to the master database with the **DAC** because master is guaranteed to be available if the instance of the Database Engine is started.

Shut down the database server and restart it with minimal configuration:

```
sqlservr.exe -f -s <instancename>
```

If it works fine, then you have a problem with your startup configurations and you need to find out which is causing you the issues.